# With JS, is it possible to block the loading of images that are statically defined in the HTML?

Tags: javascript, ajax

So I have a hand-coded one-pager site with a very long length and dozens of images. Let's skip the discussion on whether that's a great strategy, but the situation is is that rendering all these images as fast as can be can slow down the user experience, especially if he tries to scroll or interact with the page before all of the heavy image assets have been loaded.

Ideally, I'd want to delay the loading of assets until the user is on top of the section in which the images are loaded, or very near it.

So, if everything is already in there statically, i.e.:

```
<img src="images/photo.jpg" alt="Photo" />
```

Is it possible, and always successful, to do something like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("img").each(function(){
        $(this).attr("data-src", $(this).attr('src'));
        $(this).attr("src", ''); 
  })
})
```

IIRC, simply hiding all the img elements with css by setting display to none won't stop them from loading in the background. And I wasn't sure if the document.ready callback would execute before any of the assets were rendered.

Or should I just say, screw JS-disabled clients and load in assets using ajax and json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

document.ready is after everything is in DOM. Images are loaded before, if I know.

Why can't you do it like this?

```
<img data-src="yourimage.png" class="img_i_need" />
```

and if you need it, use

```
$(function() {
    $("div").click(function() {
        $(".img_i_need").each(function() {
            $(this).attr('src', $(this).attr('data-src'));
        });
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/genesis/nDq82/3/

Comment: no. there is no way for normal non-jJS clients.. maybe `<nosrcipt>&lt;img src="...." &gt;</noscript>`

Comment: To non-JS clients, put the image tags with SRC inside a <noscript> tag.

Answer (score 1):

Never screw JS-disabled clients, for any reason.

That said, your idea is what I've also thought reading your question. Dunno if it works though.

Comment: I use AJAX in my websites but I use it to fetch content from physical webpages, fetching only the content needed. So if you don't have JS enabled, you can still open the whole page.

Comment: So you're suggesting even sites such as Facebook should work without JS? (which it doesn't)

Comment: Every site is different, of course. I just say: AJAX is a great improvement for web applications, but it must be a way to give the user a richer (and hopefully better) navigation experience, and not becoming an accessibility issue. A site like facebook relies heavily on JS, and users who actually navigate on facebook would have JS enabled anyway, since they want all that fancy stuff. For a normal website which has to display content to the user, AJAX should be a plus, not something absolutely needed to navigate the site.